# vb.net app.config xml transform doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, xslt, app-config

I want to add some settings in my app.config. With the preview, settings are correctly added but not after build.

My App.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <!--<providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>-->
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BackOfficeEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.BackOfficeDAL.csdl|res://*/DAL.BackOfficeDAL.ssdl|res://*/DAL.BackOfficeDAL.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MySource;initial catalog=***;persist security info=True;user id=***;password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings />
</configuration>
```

My App.Debug.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- For more information on using transformations 
     see the web.config examples at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=214134. -->
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="inputDirectory" value="C:\Dev\Intranet_MISC\" xdt:Transform="Insert"  />
    <add key="outputDirectory" value="C:\Dev\Intranet_MISC\Traites\" xdt:Transform="Insert"  />
    <add key="historyDirectory" value="C:\Dev\Intranet_MISC\XmlHistory\" xdt:Transform="Insert"  />
    <add key="MH_ID_MOTIF_REPOS_HEBDO" value="16" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The final app.config after build:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- For more information on using transformations 
     see the web.config examples at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=214134. -->
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="inputDirectory" value="C:\Dev\Intranet_MISC\" xdt:Transform="Insert"  />
    <add key="outputDirectory" value="C:\Dev\Intranet_MISC\Traites\" xdt:Transform="Insert"  />
    <add key="historyDirectory" value="C:\Dev\Intranet_MISC\XmlHistory\" xdt:Transform="Insert"  />
    <add key="MH_ID_MOTIF_REPOS_HEBDO" value="16" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
    <add key="inputDirectory" value="C:\Dev\Intranet_MISC\"/>
    <add key="outputDirectory" value="C:\Dev\Intranet_Dekra_MISC\Traites\"/>
    <add key="historyDirectory" value="C:\Dev\Intranet_MISC\XmlHistory\"/>
    <add key="MH_ID_MOTIF_REPOS_HEBDO" value="16"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Have you any ideas on the origin of the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found. In the vbproj I have modified a attribut:

From:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AppConfig>App.$(Configuration).config</AppConfig>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

To:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AppConfig>App.config</AppConfig>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

In ohters vbproj there aren't this propertyGroup.